# Using Reflection on a referenced class library

Tags: c#, reflection

I Have A class Library

```
    namespace LabelFieldsCalc
 {
public class LabelFields
{
    // public string "--";
    public string BARCODE128(LabelCarton carton)
    {
        return "01" + carton.EanTun
            + "3102" + carton.WeightBarcode.ToString()
            + "13" + carton.ItemProdnDate.ToString()
            + "21" + carton.EstNO.ToString() + carton.StationNum.ToString() + carton.ItemSerial.ToString() + "9";
    }
    public string BARCODE128HR(LabelCarton carton)
    {
        return "(01)" + carton.EanTun
            + "(3102)" + carton.WeightBarcode.ToString()
            + "(13)" + carton.ItemProdnDate.ToString()
            + "(21)" + carton.EstNO.ToString() + carton.StationNum.ToString() + carton.ItemSerial.ToString() + "9";
    }
    public string BARCODE13PRICE(LabelCarton carton)
    {
        var LvTempEan = carton.ProdExtraKey4.Substring(1, 8);
        var LcPrice = (carton.Price1 * 100).ToString(">>>>");
        int moddigit = ModuloDigit(LvTempEan + LcPrice);
        return LvTempEan + LcPrice;
    }

    private int ModuloDigit(string v)
    {
        //int k = v.Length;
        int tot1 = 0;
        int tot2 = 0;
        for (int i = v.Length; i < 0; i -= 2)
        {
            tot1 += Convert.ToInt16(v.Substring(i, 1));
        }
        tot1 *= 3;
        for (int i = v.Length - 1; i < 0; i -= 2)
        {
            tot2 += Convert.ToInt16(v.Substring(i, 1));
        }

        tot1 += tot2;

        int k = (tot1.ToString().Length);
        int m = Convert.ToInt16(tot1.ToString().Substring(k, 1));
        if (m == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 10 - m;
    }
}
}
```

that is referenced in a project

I can get at the methods if I do

```
        LabelFields lv = new LabelFields();
        string value = lv.BARCODE128HR(LL);
```

But what I actually need to do is to use reflection so that I can decide which method I to use to calculate value at run time

What I have tried is

```
        Type type = typeof(LabelFields);
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        string res2 = (string)type.InvokeMember("BARCODE128HR", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, mParam);
```

this gives me

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131512
  Message=Attempted to access a missing member.
```

What am I missing to get the reflection working

Comment: What is the type of mParam? Must be LabelCarton, otherwise there is no matching signature.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need reflection in the first place? Once you instantiated your obj type of LabelFields, you can call its methods directly.

```
   Type type = typeof(LabelFields);
   LabelFields obj = (LabelFields)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   obj.BARCODE128HR(....);
```

**Edit:**
Your method name is a parameter coming from outside. I'd suggest using an enumeration and a switch:

```
public enum MethodNames {
   BARCODE128,
   BARCODE128HR, etc
}

/// later
LabelFields obj = new LabelFields();
string lv = "";
switch (MethodName) {
  case MethodNames.BARCODE128:
       lv = obj.BARCODE128HR(mParam);
       break;
  ///and the rest
}
```

Comment: Reflection seems to be the best answer to because I only know what method I need at run time the method name to be used comes from a variable input

Comment: You have to check for valid method name anyway since only the implemented methods could be called. I would use an enumerated list of options and a switch and call the method directly. If you happen to have any obfuscation in place it would break your code.

Comment: @ PepitoSh thanks you got the error with your previous comment I had the mParam Type wrong reply and I'll mark it as an answer. Your solution here suffers from indelibly ling the calling program to the class library, and any change in the class library i.e. a new method would require recoding  in the calling program, hence the use of reflection

Comment: If this is a concern, I'd recommend an additional method to query the supported method names and check against this list before an actual call.